# Maven checkstyle plugin: Print warnings to console

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3, checkstyle

I cant seem to figure out how to get maven-checkstyle-plugin to print warnings to the console when I run the check goal.

If I configure as:

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="NPathComplexity">
            <property name="max" value="5" />
            <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

...i see nothing in console and the check does not fail. If I change the severity to error, the check fails.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Plugin config is as follows

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                    <configLocation>
                        rules.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom snippet with the configuration?

Comment: Have you tried to run mvn clean verify ? Why have you configured the phase compile ? Just try the default without phase and try mvn clean verify.

Comment: @khmarbaise compile is before verify in the default lifecycle. I can run it when it makes sense for my project, the phase should not affect the output.

Comment: I know that compile is before verify but i suggested to test exactly what you mentioned if there is not influence with that.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem.  This configuration worked for me.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>checkstyle</id>
           <goals>
               <goal>checkstyle</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is a different goal. The point of using check goal is to fail the build. So if I do this then Ill have to run checkstyle twice, once with check goal to fail on error violations, and once with checkstyle goal to print warning violations to the console (which isn't even its main purpose). Checkstyle is too expensive to have to run twice like this

Comment: ah, but I see you have configured consoleOutput to true for all executions, which does fix the problem of not writing audit events to the console. There is a problem though https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-421

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>` to the `<configuration>` in the pom.xml worked for me:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
            ...
            </executions>
            ...
        </plugin>
```

Also, I have this in my checkstyle.xml:

```
       <module name="Checker">

          <module name="SeverityMatchFilter">
              <!-- report all violations except ignore -->
              <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
              <property name="acceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
          </module>

          ...

      </module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to explicitly add the check goal to printout the information to the consoles as [mentioned in the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/).

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execute>
        <id>check</id>
        <goals><goal>check</goal></goals>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <execute>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Depending how you call mvn you need to change the phase in which the check will be done. The default binding for the maven-checkstyle-plugin is the verfiy phase. Either you give an explicit phase in the executions block or you just do mvn clean verify and you can omit the phase entry.